# CRM 2016:Using Web API for CRM IFD to connect CRM Web Service

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, adal, dynamics-crm-2016, dynamics-crm-webapi

I'm new to Web API and trying to build a CRM Web Service application with C# by using Web API. Here is the sample code I'm using: [C# application which authenticates against Azure AD using ADAL and communicates with Dynamics CRM.](https://github.com/jlattimer/CrmWebApiCSharp)

This code works perfectly for AD authentication on premise CRM environment. But my environment is IFD, which means I have to use OAuth. it says method calls to the web services must be authorized with the identity provider for that service endpoint. However all the example point to Microsoft Azure Active Directory. but for real case, do we have to register a CRM app with Azure Active Directory?

Then how can I define the 'Client ID', 'RedirectUrl', 'Authority' in my code, where is my endppoint? We're using ADFS authentication.

Can anyone share some sample codes for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  My thought is you'd have to register your App on your on-prem ADFS for CRM and authenticate using OAuth just like you would with CRM Online.  For example, the PS command on ADFS would be something like:

> Add-AdfsClient -ClientId <SomeGuid> -Name "SomeName" -RedirectUri http://someurl